# Solving a system of first order differential equations and second order differential equations (Non-linear)

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory, differential-equations

**The problem**

I currently have a system of four equations. Two are second-order differential equations and two are first-order differential equations:

[Four equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQtr6.png)

The initial conditions are:

```
x = 0 |
y = 0.3 | 
f(x) = 2.05 |
f(y) = 0.55 |
```

All angles are in degrees.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use Google Colabs and worked with SciPy and NumPy. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to program it as these equations are non-linear. Could somebody give me some tips on any other modules to use?

Comment: This is just not possible. When you have the first derivative given, the second follows automatically and is not freely available. As your system is highly structured, it would be good if you could reflect back to the genesis of these equations. The first two are the general ballistic projectile equations `v'=g-c*v*|v|`, where then `x'=v` for the position integration (`x,v,g` being vectors). Where does the prescription of the solution form for `v` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy has a [Runge Kutta solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html). First, you have to transform your ODEs to first order system (you can always do that by setting z=y') and then try the RK solver.